# _SERVER["PATH"] not being set from FcgidInitialEnv PATH

Tags: php, apache, fastcgi

I'm setting up a new PHP environment using PHP 5.4.20, Apache 2.4.6 VC10 and FastCGI 2.3.9 on a Windows 7 machine.

In my httpd.conf, I load the FastCGI module, and set the PATH

```
LoadModule fcgid_module modules/mod_fcgid.so
FcgidInitialEnv PATH "c:/wamp/bin/php/php5.4.20;C:/WINDOWS/system32;C:/WINDOWS;C:/WINDOWS/System32/Wbem;"
FcgidMaxRequestsPerProcess 1000 
FcgidMaxProcesses 50
FcgidMaxRequestLen 1073741824
FcgidBusyTimeout 360
FcgidIOTimeout 360
FcgidInitialEnv PHPRC "c:/wamp/bin/php/php5.4.20"
FcgidInitialEnv PHP_FCGI_MAX_REQUESTS 1000
AddHandler fcgid-script .php
FcgidWrapper "c:/wamp/bin/php/php5.4.20/php-cgi.exe" .php
```

However, when viewing phpinfo(), the Environment PATH is set according to the config above, but _SERVER["PATH"] seems to be set from cmd.

How can I force the _SERVER["PATH"] to be the same as the Environment PATH?

Answer (score 0):

To override _SERVER["PATH"] in Apache, you need to use SetEnv PATH, even if using FastCGI.

```
SetEnv PATH "c:/wamp/bin/php/php5.4.20;C:/WINDOWS/system32;C:/WINDOWS;C:/WINDOWS/System32/Wbem;"
```